# How to Re-Layout UITableViewCell with added Views on Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a scenario in my app, in which I have to create a UITableViewCell content in runtime, depending on values I get from network. I'll try to explain what I try to achieve and the issues I am facing. Instead of a specific answer I would like to hear a general solution for this whole problem.

**Attempts**

- I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell which has some container views that could include views depending on runtime values.
- UITableViewCell has been designed using storyboard with auto layout enabled.
- For the views that would contain dynamic views, I have defined a height constraint to be `v.height >= 0`. But the height on interface builder is bigger than zero and I would expect cell re-layout after adding views.
- The dynamic views are typically rows which are added vertically, but there is a scenario that I'm adding views horizontally.
- I have used [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView), an alternative to UIStackView for pre-iOS9 devices.
- I add my dynamic views on `awakeFromNib` method of my custom UITableViewCell
- I tried to call some methods in hopes they would update my layout. The last one I used `[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`
- On my view controller that includes UITableView I tried

  `myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300;`

And

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }`

**Findings and Issues**

- My UITableViewCell seems to be created and the dynamic views. However it looks like the total height of the cell is exactly the same as the one I defined with storyboard.
- View container heights are also the same as I designed them on storyboard, looks like v.height >= 0 is not the only constraint affecting those views (I haven't defined any other constraint regarding to height attribute)
- The first view seem to be added nicely, but the other views are quite stretch (I think it's because no place for them)

Can you please help me to find a solution for this general problem? Thank you

Edit: cell image on request [image]

Comment: add images of storyboard.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy added

Comment: You wanted to add views horizontally?? Or vertically?? Can you please expalnlin the image too which part of cell do what. Like your update status portion is static what about other if you relate you question with image that will be better and add constraints of each view too bcz your solution is depending on each components.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I think I have specified that in question. I do not look for a specific answer, I would rather prefer a generic solution. I may or may not add views, vertically or horizontally. My cell need to adapt changing view situations. I want my cell to update itself based on the dynamic contents and show correctly on my table view. Do you mean that the UI I specify on storyboard is static and preserved as such?

Comment: I got it you wanted dynamic `UItableViewCell` as per the data coming from the server. Thats OK! but what type of data it is like image and label etc. and how you wanted to arrange them. this point I didn't get.

Comment: You should relax a bit. You are not obligated to answer this question.